# calculation within table row by row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in database as followings:

```
   locationname postcode locationlatitude locationlongitude
   --------------------------------------------------------

 1. gsfs        2322.    352353.           35235235 
 2. gsfs        2322.    352443.           352353 
 3. gsfs        2322.    352353.           35235235
```

.
.

I want to calculate the distance between each location to all locations in the table(many to many). I have been able to compute one-to-many and one-to-one calculation but I couldn't figure out how to calculate distance from every location to every location. Do I have to use nested loop or not? Should I have to fetch all the data into an array first? Can you please help me out with this. I don't know whether my question is clear or not.

I have tried but I couldn't execute it due to errors and stupid mistakes.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, locationname, locationlatitude, locationlongitude, postcode FROM distancetable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
 
$i=0;
$j=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    for ($row=0; $row <num_rows ; $row++) { 
        $lat1=$row[$i]["locationlatitude"];
        $long1=$row[$i]["locationlongitude"];
        $suburb1=$row[$i]["locationname"];
        $lat2=$row[$j]["locationlatitude"];
        $long2=$row[$j]["locationlongitude"];
        $suburb2=$row[$j]["locationname"];
    
        $distance=Round(ACOS(SIN(PI()*$long1/180)*SIN(PI()*$long2/180)+COS(PI()*$long1/180)*COS(PI()*$long2/180)*COS(PI()*$lat1/180-PI()*$lat2/180))*6371,3);

        echo  nl2br (" \n ");
        echo $row[id]. ". Distance between " .$suburb1. " to " .$suburb2. "=" .$distance;
        $i++;
        $j++;
```

Comment: What db are you using?  Sounds like a case for a self-joining query

Comment: i am using mysql db

Answer (score 0):

So I made a table like this:

```
create table latlongdata (
    id int auto_increment primary key not null,
    locationname varchar(35) not null,
    postcode char(5) not null,
    locationlatitude numeric(6, 3) not null,
    locationlongitude numeric(6,3) not null
);
```

then I added some sample lat/long values like so:

```
insert into latlongdata (locationname, postcode, locationlatitude, locationlongitude)
VALUES
       ('Fenwick, MI', '48834',43.142,-85.049),
       ('Andover, MN', '55304', 45.255, -93.287),
       ('Minneapolis, MN', '55422', 45.015, -93.340),
       ('Lydia, SC', '29079', 34.296, -81.113);
```

then I made a query like so:

```
select
    a.postcode as FromPostCode,
       b.postcode as ToPostCode,
       round(acos(sin(pi()*a.locationlongitude/180)*sin(pi()*b.locationlongitude/180)+cos(pi()*b.locationlongitude/180)*cos(pi()*a.locationlatitude/180-pi()*b.locationlatitude/180))*6731, 3) as distance
from latlongdata a
inner join latlongdata b
where b.id > a.id;
```

...which should be close to what you want, but I think there might be something wrong with your math since the results didn't make a lot of sense.  But that should be how you do it.

Note the self-join with the inequality operator on the SELECT statement.  This will prevent you from calculating B -> A after you've already calculated A -> B.  Fair warning: With a large table, you should expect the result set for this to be... large.  It might be better to directly insert the results into a new table (assuming you have sufficient storage space) than try to select out the results.